# Steroids Connect: What is the URL for the preview QR code?

Tags: steroids

Running `steroids connect` ordinarily opens a browser with a big QR code for testing on a real device. But I'm running it on a VPS so it doesn't open a browser.

What is the URL that this opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What mr. Jones said! Also, you can run `steroids connect --debug` to see the URL that it is trying to open in the console log.

Answer (score 1):

Its going to be unique per user but here's mine

```
http://localhost:4567/__connect/connect.html?qrcode=appgyver%3A%2F%2F%3Fips%3D%255B%2522192.168.1.150%2522%255D%26port%3D4567#/connect
```

You can see in that string an encoded IP LAN address (92.168.1.150)
You can also see the port (4567)

If that helps then great.